# URL rewriting in ASP.Net Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, umbraco

I have a URL like this `www.mydomain.com/brands/bname` and I want to rewrite it to `www.mydomain.com/bname` I have done some logic like this

```
<add name="301_bname" redirectMode="Permanent" redirect="Domain" ignoreCase="true"
        rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
        virtualUrl="http://(?:www.)??mydomain.com/brands/bname`"
        destinationUrl="www.mydomain.com/bname`" />
```

but the problem is that this works only when I hardcode `bname`.And in my case this bname is dynamic..What I can do to overcome this?
Note:I am new in URL rewriting case ,so if you found any mistake in my current code,you can always point out..

Comment: Where does that XML go in the Umbraco project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to redirect/rewrite `/brandName_x` to `/brands/brandName_x`, you need to setup a virtual URL that redirects to a real one.

```
<add name="redirect_brands" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true"
rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
virtualUrl="^/(.*)$" destinationUrl="^/brands/$1" />
```

In the above line the virtualUrl is looking for a string "/brandName_x" which will be redirected to "/brands/brandName_x" which is where the actual node is located.

To achieve the opposite, you can do this:

```
<add name="redirect_brands" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true"
rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
virtualUrl="^/brands/(.*)$" destinationUrl="^/$1" />
```

Comment: Actually I want to achieve the opposite of what you told..please check the question and correct the answer.

Comment: Added the opposite case as well. But in your initial code, you have back-ticks in the virtualUrl and in the destinationUrl. Not sure if that will work out well.

Comment: For Umbraco noobs the answer could be improved by mentioning where this should be added ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<add name="301_bname" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true"
rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" virtualUrl="^~/brands/(.*)"
destinationUrl="~/$1" />
```

The `virtualUrl` parameter uses a regular expression to match the incoming URL. You can then use the `$1` notation to pass the pattern to the `destinationUrl` parameter.

Since both urls are on the same domain, and (I assume) within your web application, you don't need the `redirect="Domain"` part, and you can use relative URL paths.

Comment: after applying your code URL always redirected to home page(main domain)

Comment: It doesn't answer your question directly, but if you are using IIS7, you can use the URL rewrite module http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite which might make life easier!